# Changing visibility with LinearLayout and weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

So I have a `LinearLayout` with two view and I am setting weight to each views.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/main_layout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.sorted.view.SorteddTextView
                        android:id="@+id/percent1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@color/sky_blue"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text="0%"
                        android:textColor="@color/font_color"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/frame1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="8">
                        ......
                        ......
                       </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now at first I set the visibility to `GONE` from activity. Then on some button press I set the visibility to `VISIBLE` but I am not able to see the view. 
However when visibility is `INVISIBLE` and then if I change it to `VISIBLE` its working fine.

What I think is `LinearLayout` is unable to  adjust its view(well I have no idea).

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: in short GONE to VISIBLE not working. INVISIBLE to VISIBLE working fine for the view

Answer (score 1):

You should add `android:weightSum` to your parent`LinearLayout`

```
    <LinearLayout       ...
                        android:id="@+id/main_layout1"
                        android:weightSum="10"
                        >

                        <com.sorted.view.SorteddTextView
                            android:id="@+id/percent1"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                           />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:layout_weight="8">
                        ...
                        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

`VISIBLE`
[image]
`INVISIBLE`
[image]
`GONE`
[image]

I also set visibility in `onCreate()` and it provide a layout as same as I set in xml

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

//        btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//        btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        btn2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: Tried this already. Its just  making the FrameLayout to be in center.

Comment: Its woking fine when SorteddTextView is invisible. Having problem with GONE

Comment: @SonuRaj i'm not sure why you get that, but i used to create a demo and it work

Comment: this is happening when I am changing the visibility from Activity.

Comment: Can you please try changing the visibility from activity!

Comment: @SonuRaj yes I did it but still not get the error like you

Comment: Is it because I am using a listView and setting the visibility from adapter?

Comment: @SonuRaj sorry, i don't know about it

Comment: @SonuRaj You've probably found an answer by now, but for me removing the weight_sum attribute of the LinearLayout did work.

Answer (score 0):

An if you try to put TableRow ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <com.sorted.view.SorteddTextView
            android:id="@+id/percent1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"                
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0%"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

        </FrameLayout>
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you make the first `view` as  `Visibility GONE`, it hides like it is supposed to, and the space is adjusted by the other `view` which is inside the `LinearLayout`. That means all the available space is now occupied by the second `view`. Now when you make the first `view` `visible` again, you cannot see it because it is overlapped by the other view which is already occupying the whole of the space in the `LinearLayout`
A work around to this problem would be, to assign `weightSum` to the `LinearLayout` which will always make sure out of `weight=10`, 2 is for the first `view` and the remaining 8 is for second `view` always. Hope it helps.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/main_layout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:gravity="center" android:weightSum="10"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
```